# Tag request: video conversion

Tags: discussion, tags

A lot of a questions here are related to converting the video output of an old console or computer to a newer monitor (VGA/HDMI, etc.). I'm thinking it would be good to have a tag specifically for this topic, like `[video-conversion]`. But that name could be erroneously applied to topics about converting from [Amiga .anim files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANIM) to .avi or .mpg.

Anyway, it would cover:

- Physical video connectors (SCART, HD15, DE-9, RCA, etc.)
- Sync conversion (HVSync, CSYNC, SOG, sync on composite video, etc.)
- Analog/digital conversion (RGBI to VGA or VGA to HDMI/DVI-D), analog/analog (composite/S-Video to VGA), or digital/digital (RGBI to HDMI/DVI-D)

Is this topic worth a tag and if so, what would be a good tag name for it?

Answer (score 1):

I do think such a tag would be useful. *video-conversion*, however, can be a bit misleading as you rightly say.

> *video-adapters*
>
> *screen-adapters*

or

> *video-output-conversion*

might be better.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a tag for this would be useful.  The usage guidance of tags related to file conversion could then be amended to include a reference to the new tag to try to stop the mis-tagging that you describe.

As to what to call it, perhaps use the word *display* rather than *video*?  That can suggest that it is more hardware-oriented.

Comment: To me (uk eng), the ambiguity is biased the other way. Display means to me the image, video means the interface - but it's a very weak preference. It may also be an artefact of learning the terminology in the '80s.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane I (uk eng) agree with Chenmunka (uk eng) in the way that the ambiguity lies in terms of hardware / software, but to me the display is the thing that shows the picture and the video adapter is the thing that sends the signal... so I'd prefer [video-*] but for different reasons. And now _video_ has stopped seeming like a real word, so I can't really analyse this more at the moment.

Comment: Usage-guidance is hardly read by anybody, apparently...